# Merge images into one using canvas not working properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am merging multiple image into one using javascript. But The canvas created using javascript is displayed as black. I know the default bg color of canvas is transparent but something wrong is happening in my case.

HTML:

```
<div class="sampleImages">
    <img src="xyz.png" />
    <img src="abc.png" />
</div>
<br>
<button type="button">Convert to single img</button>
<br>
<img id="result" />
```

JS :

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var c=document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width=250;
    c.height=250;
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    $(".sampleImages>img").each(function(index){
        ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
    });
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    $("#result").attr("src",dataURL);
});
```

Written fiddle for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/reoo21kq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `image/jpg` does not accept alpha values (trasparency), you should render your data to any format that does, like`image/png`.

```
var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
```

See this corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0af968vc/)

Comment: ohhh.. how can i miss that...well thanks a lot.. its working well now